# Property does not exist on populated document mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Let's say I have two schemas:

Foo.ts

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IFoo extends Document {
  name: string;
}

const fooSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  }
);


export default mongoose.model<IFoo>('Foo', fooSchema);
```

And Bar.ts

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IBar extends Document {
  fooId: string | IFoo; // can be string or can be Foo document
}

const barSchema = new Schema(
  {
    fooId: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Foo',
      required: true,
    },
    title: String;
  }
);


export default mongoose.model<IBar>('Bar', barSchema);
```

Now when I find a `Bar` document with `Foo` populated. I get a compilation error from typescript

```js
const bar = await Bar.findOne({ title: 'hello' }).populate({ path: 'fooId', model: 'Foo' });

bar.fooId.name // here typescript gives an error
```

The error is

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'

Since I've defined in `IBar` that `fooId` can be `string | IFoo`. Why typescript is complaining? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [typings](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/d250ddc/index.d.ts#L559) of the `populate` method you can see that it's result type is simply `this`. So, before addressing `name` field of the `fooId` property you have to explicitly narrow the type of the result to `IFoo` type:

```ts
const bar = await Bar.findOne({ title: 'hello' })
    .populate({ path: 'fooId', model: 'Foo' });

if (typeof bar.fooId !== 'string') { // discards the `string` type
    bar.fooId.name
}
```

Or just simply [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the result:

```ts
const bar = await Bar.findOne({ title: 'hello' })
    .populate({ path: 'fooId', model: 'Foo' });


(bar.fooId as IFoo).name
```